# Extract report from Azure AD for Guest user Invitee

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm looking for a way to extract report of my guest users in Azure AD with details who was the original invitee of each guest user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Audit logs feature under Monitoring part in Azure Active Directory. Add filters to get the data you want and then download it if you want.

[image]

Comment: any idea how to get details for more than 30 days as audit logs were limited to 30 days..

Comment: @Afzal If you need retain the audit logs longer than the default retention period, you can route it to an Azure storage using Azure Monitor, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/quickstart-azure-monitor-route-logs-to-storage-account